# Postman Calls to Autotask

Tags: api, postman

I am trying to make a call to Autotask using postman.

I have my userName, Key and TrackingIdentifier

UserName = notGonaShareThis@email.com

Pw = orThis

TrackingIdentifier = 123abcNumbersAndLetters321cba

URI = https://webservices/autotask.net/atservices/1.6/getZoneInfo

However, I'm getting this error that I'm not sure how to handle.

[postman-autotask-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS5b6.png)

***this is the stack trace**

[postman-autotask-error-stack-trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a7aL.png)

Comment: Good to see the error, but maybe just copy the error text inline; the links will go bad some day.  Also, since you are using Postman, can you edit your question to include the raw request that postman is sending in the HTTP payload rather than just the "key = value" pairs?  You can see that by clicking the "code" link on the top right of the request panel in Postman.  Don't forget to replace the sensitive stuff like tokens and credentials.  You are getting a SOAP exception, and the message says "Invalid domain".  I'm guessing the domain is referring to the email address in your username.

Comment: `URI = https://webservices/autotask.net/atservices/1.6/getZoneInfo`
The URI should be `https://webservices.autotask.net/atservices/1.6/getZoneInfo` (note the dot (,) instead of the slash (/) after `https://webservices`)